# thread_local template variable of struct inside anonymous namespace fails to link?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, clang

The following example program uses a thread local template variable, and instantiates it using a type inside an anonymous namespace.  This produces a linker error in `gcc`.  In `clang` it actually compiles but does not run correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T>
struct container {
    container()  { printf("construct: %p\n", this); }
    ~container() { printf("destruct: %p\n", this);  }
};

template<typename T>
thread_local container<T> storage;

namespace {
    struct bar {};
}

int main() {
    auto& ref1 = storage<bar>;
    auto& ref2 = storage<bar>;
}
```

On gcc this fails with a link error:

```
a.cpp:6:2: warning: ‘container<T>::~container() noexcept [with T = {anonymous}::bar]’ used but never defined
  ~container() { printf("destruct: %p\n", this);  }
  ^
/tmp/ccgh0P15.o: In function `__tls_init':
a.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `container<(anonymous namespace)::bar>::~container()'
```

With clang the program compiles but produces very troubling output:

```
construct: 0x7fb8d1c003d0
construct: 0x7fb8d1c003d0
destruct: 0x7fb8d1c003d0
destruct: 0x7fb8d1c003d0
```

Are there some rough edges surrounding thread_local/templated variables that I am running into here?  I am unclear why this would ever produce a link error (the link error disappears if I remove thread_local).  In the case of clang how could a double destroy of an object with static storage duration be anything but a compiler bug?  In clang the issue disappears if I remove the anonymous namespace OR the thread_local specification, OR by removing one of the references in main().

Can anyone shed some light on this, I am mainly just curious if I am misunderstanding something.  Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
clang++ -v

Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)

g++ -v

gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Comment: This is the entire program.

Comment: Ok, that's indeed quite interesting. I assume what troubles you about the clang output is that the ctor/dtor apparently run twice?

Comment: Yes, I should have been a bit more clear.  The object is constructed twice then destructed twice which definitely seems invalid to me.

Comment: Also, disregard my comment from further up concerning UB, I wrote this based on an incorrect understanding of what it is that you are doing here.